# Mongoose save multiple updated documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a situation where I need to update multiple documents in a collection, but each update is logic-driven and is not uniform. In other words, I don't want to apply *the same update* to every affected document. Each document's changes will be driven by some logic on the system.

After this logic has been executed, I have an array of documents that have been edited in application space using standard JS operations like:

```
someDocument.someField = "some new value";
someDocument.someRef = otherDocument._id;
editedDocs.push(someDocument);
```

Then I normally do something like:

```
for (let i = 0; i < editedDocs.length; i++) {
  await editedDocs[i].save({session});
}
```

I put the updates into a transaction so they succeed/fail atomically. But I've noticed this approach is slow and one edit of ~200 documents took about 15 seconds to complete.

What I'm looking for is the ability to save all the documents in the editedDocs array in one function call.

Does such a call exist?

Thanks!

Comment: you can bundle multiple updates in single bulkWrite operation : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/?_ga=2.182803174.1538742925.1670001653-1341466864.1641598014#db.collection.bulkwrite--

Comment: @R2D2 thanks. This was not exactly what I needed, but it pointed me in the right direction. Have a great weekend

Answer (score 0):

@R2D2 answered my question in the form of a comment.

It actually pointed me in the right direction. The operation I wanted was actually Model.bulkSave() which uses Model.bulkWrite() ultimately.

I also had to update Mongoose from 5.x to the latest version because Model.bulkSave() in version 5.x doesn't respect transactions. In version 6.x it does, so I can save multiple documents that were edited in application space in one call without looping within a transaction, which met all my requirements.

See here for more information: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-bulkSave

Thanks @R2D2